# Block Ram in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I am working on A VHDL project which is utilizing Blocl Ram, but due to some reason I want to replace the Block Ram with registers, Is that possible? and how can I proceed further?

Regards

Comment: Block RAM is not a VHDL construct, but FPGA specific. And why the "Basic" tag? Are you programming FPGA's in Basic? Anyhow: read the FPGA suppliers synthesis documentation/user guide on distributed ram.

Comment: Actually, my supervisor is going to fabricate that VHDL project on ASIC chip, therefore I need to replace Bram with registers.

Comment: Instead of instantiating a block RAM black box from Xilinx library in your design, model the memory you need in plain VHDL and the ASIC synthesis tool will do the rest. And if you follow the Xilinx recommendations for block RAM inference, with the same VHDL code, Vivado will continue using block RAMs.

Comment: I'm a newbie in VHDL, and I'm working on a project which already contains bram and ram controller.

Comment: So as a newbie your are going to design an ASIC... wow. You know that if you get it wrong, it's $50,000-100.000 down the drain? But anyhow: you cannot 'simply' replace every block ram with registers. It depends very much on the design.

Comment: I am not going to design it, the project i'm working on is part of my thesis. i wrote VHDL synthesisable code for Artix 7 Fpga, it's part of a baseband communication system, and a coworker of my supervisor also wants to use it who is working on ASIC design.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to create a register island for that, however it's not a good idea unless you need to read the slots/registers concurrently. ASIC libraries have RAM macros.

You could do something like below by putting it into a clocked `process`.

```
if (address = 0) then
    if (write_enable = '1') then
        reg0 <= data_in;
    end if;
    data_out <= reg0;
elsif (address = 1) then
    if (write_enable = '1') then
        reg1 <= data_in;
    end if;
    data_out <= reg1;
-- and so on
end if;
```